# Dropdown cut off in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I'm having problem with ALL dropdown menus in app. I'm implementing Bootstrap 4 and in previous version v3 the dropdowns were shown correctly but it looks like this now:

[image]

The usage of dropdown elements in HTML view is pretty straightforward:

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RequestLodgingID, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RequestLodgingID, Model.LodgingSelectList, new { Class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RequestLodgingID)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RequestLodgingSizeID, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RequestLodgingSizeID, Model.LodgingSizeSelectList, new { Class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RequestLodgingSizeID)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I've no idea how this started happening and what am I missing exactly?

Comment: For everyone wondering, check below, Ive found the solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: solved it by adding 'input-sm' class:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RequestLodgingID, Model.LodgingSelectList, new { Class = "form-control input-sm" })
```